# Xcode code coverage for third party framework

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage

I have a rather weird task on hands. (Developing objective-c application on iOS)

I want to find out code coverage for a third party framework. I am working on a test application Y, to which I added framework X.  Test application is meant to be developed in a way, that it exercises as much functionality from framework X, as possible.  At this point, I need to find out what is the code coverage at the moment.

From framework X I have only public header files available.
Application Y, is just a typical try-it-all demo application, in which user is able to press buttons and do something with framework. (So it has many calls to framework X.

As far as I have read, code coverage on xcode is usually done - by having application, then having unit tests, and code coverage checks how much of application methods is covered in tests. But in this case, I want a coverage from my test app - to framework. (public API calls).

I tried using this article: https://medium.com/xcblog/xccov-xcode-code-coverage-report-for-humans-466a4865aa18, but it only gives me out all methods/calls from my application itself and no calls from framework.

Also from this - same thing.  https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/xcode-and-code-coverage-c0bfa36192ba. But it should be possible to get the coverage for public calls, right?

Between older solutions, I read also this, http://nsbogan.com/mobile%20ci/2015/02/08/code-coverage-for-ios and it also required for me to flush out `__gcov_flush();` all coverage at one point. (Which still did not result in coverage for third party frameworks). Makes me think - maybe the framework also needs to be coded with coverage flags and flush?

An example framework would be Sentry:

[image]

with it's SentryEvent instance method:

```
/**
* Init an SentryEvent will set all needed fields by default
* @param level SentrySeverity
* @return SentryEvent
*/
- (instancetype)initWithLevel:(enum SentrySeverity)level;
```

Hopefully someone can lead me in right direction.